# Can I create clickable td tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html code has "a" tag inside "td" tag like below code.

```
<td align="left"> <a href="besir.html" target="_blank">  KASSAB Besir </a> </td>
```

I want to add new clickable line to my table with javascript. My js code is given below.

```
const createTD = document.createElement('td');
const createTDA = document.createElement('a');
createTD.align = "left";
createTD.innerHTML = "SURNAME Name";
createTDA.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.exampleurl.com');
createTD.appendChild(createTDA);
```

A new row is added to the table but the above code is not working properly. td is created but not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is *almost* working; the mistake you made was setting the text in the innerHTML of the table cell, instead of the anchor tag -- so the link existed, it was just invisible because there was nothing inside it.

Here's a corrected version (with some extra code to demonstrate its usage, since you omitted the part that actually attaches anything to the DOM)

```js
function AddTD() {

  const createTD = document.createElement('td');
  const createTDA = document.createElement('a');
  createTD.align = "left";
  createTDA.innerHTML = "SURNAME Name"; // <-- changed this
  createTDA.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.example.com');
  createTD.appendChild(createTDA);

  // added code to append the new cell to the table:
  document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].appendChild(createTD)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
</table>


<button onclick="AddTD()">Add</button>
```

It's maybe worth noting that you can do this more easily and readably by inserting the full html string instead of using individual DOM methods:

```js
function AddTD() {

  const createTD = `<td align="left"><a href="//example.com">SURNAME name</a></td>`;

  document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].innerHTML += createTD
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
</table>


<button onclick="AddTD()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are appending an empty `<a>` tag since you are not using `innerHTML` for it

```
createTD.innerHTML = "SURNAME Name";  // Incorrect

createTDA.innerHTML = "SURNAME Name";  // Correct
```

#### Try it here

```js
const createTD = document.createElement('td');
const createTDA = document.createElement('a');
createTD.align = "left";
createTDA.innerHTML = "SURNAME Name";
createTDA.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.exampleurl.com');
createTD.appendChild(createTDA);

document.body.append(createTD);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
function createAnchorTag() {
                  
                // Create anchor element.
                let a = document.createElement('a'); 
                  
                // Create the text node for anchor element.
                let link = document.createTextNode("This is link");
                  
                // Append the text node to anchor element.
                a.appendChild(link); 
                  
                // Set the title.
                a.title = "This is Link"; 
                  
                // Set the href property.
                a.href = "https://example.org"; 
                  
                // Return newly anchor tag
                return a; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem  here is that you're trying to make click on an empty a tag. Try to put some text on the a tag then you'll see that it works. In any case, if you are looking for add click function to any html tag, you can do that with listeners or adding the listener like the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let tableBody = document.getElementById('table-body');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let href = 'https://google.com/';
let text = 'Google';

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let link = 
    `<tr><td><a href="${href}" target="_blank">${text}</a></td></tr>`;
  tableBody.innerHTML += link;
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="table-body">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="btn">ADD</button>
```